# Amazon s3 textract bucket to extract table from images

Tags: python

I am using Amason s3 textract bucket to extract table from images, in some images i facing an issue regarding the cell detection.
The cell detection using bounding box goes slanting in some image,[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsSSi.png)

what causing this problem and how to fix it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: can you share the code you are using to overlay the cells? It is likely that you are using rectangular bounding box when you should use the polygon information to draw the correct boundaries, because Textract has rotated your image to improve the recognition.